# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused django to heroku

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku

I'm using django with mongodb atlas and trying to deploy using heroku. Somehow I keep facing `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused` this error.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0-xb9zh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        }
    }
```

For django setting.py I simply changed it from `sqlite` to mongodb. It works perfectly in my local. There is one change I am suspicious is I had to change a `mongo_client.py` file from localhost to the connection string in order to make my mongodb connect to atlas instead of my local database. Not sure if that has anything to do with this.

```
class MongoClient(common.BaseObject):
    """
    A client-side representation of a MongoDB cluster.

    Instances can represent either a standalone MongoDB server, a replica
    set, or a sharded cluster. Instances of this class are responsible for
    maintaining up-to-date state of the cluster, and possibly cache
    resources related to this, including background threads for monitoring,
    and connection pools.
    """
    HOST = "mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0-xb9zh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    PORT = 27017
    # Define order to retrieve options from ClientOptions for __repr__.
```

Answer (score 1):

This error usually arises when you haven't white listed the IP your client is running on. See the details here:

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: I did have an ip but it was for my localhost. I tried everywhere but it still does not work.

Comment: That link in your post is a link to MongoDB Atlas. If you point it at localhost you need to download and run MongoDB locally.

Comment: Yes I am actually trying to link it to mongodb atlas. That is the problem.

Comment: You need to login to Atlas, make sure the cluster is running and that your IP address for your local client is in the list of whitelisted addresses for the cluster. Server Selection TImeout error is the client telling you it couldn't connect to the remote cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if this helps much, but you could also this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb+srv://<URL>',
            'username': 'something',
            'password': 'somepass',
            'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
        }
    }
}
```

It helped me, but for u it might not be the case.