# Flask TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable during Heroku Deployment

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, heroku

I am not sure why I am getting this TypeError:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    db = MongoEngine(app)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mongoengine/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, config)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mongoengine/__init__.py", line 134, in init_app
    connections = create_connections(config)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mongoengine/connection.py", line 108, in create_connections
    conn_settings = get_connection_settings(config)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mongoengine/connection.py", line 95, in get_connection_settings
    return _sanitize_settings(config)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mongoengine/connection.py", line 32, in _sanitize_settings
    if "://" in resolved_settings.get('host', ''):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I have set config var on my heroku app:
FLASK_APP = run.py

I can't figure out what's the main reason for that error. Please help.

My run.py script code:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=False, threaded=True)
```

Config.py Script looks like:

```
import os

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    MONGODB_HOST = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/iky-ai"

    # Intent Classifier model details
    MODELS_DIR = "model_files/"
    INTENT_MODEL_NAME = "intent.model"
    DEFAULT_FALLBACK_INTENT_NAME = "fallback"
    DEFAULT_WELCOME_INTENT_NAME = "init_conversation"
    USE_WORD_VECTORS = True


class Development(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class Production(Config):
    # MongoDB Database Details
    MONGODB_HOST = "mongodb://mongodb:27017/iky-ai"

    # Web Server details
    WEB_SERVER_PORT = 8001

class Heroku(Production):
    MONGODB_HOST = os.environ.get('MONGO_URL')
```

Procfile looks like:

```
release: APPLICATION_ENV="Heroku" python manage.py migrate
web: APPLICATION_ENV="Heroku" gunicorn -k gevent run:app
```

github link: https://github.com/ihpolash/ai-chatbot-framework

Please help someone!

Comment: please provide the full relevant code for the problem. Where you are initializing mongodb and also provide the structure of you folder with procfile.

Comment: Look like you had messed the config. How you are  defining database url in config

Comment: Updated my issue. Here is the git repo of that project: https://github.com/ihpolash/ai-chatbot-framework

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because that line in flask-mongoengine `resolved_settings.get('host', '')` is returning None, most likely because MONGODB_HOST is `None`.

Looking at your Heroku config class, it sounds like `os.environ.get('MONGO_URL')` returns None, meaning "MONGO_URL" env var is not set properly.

Comment: Thanks! Solved that issue. Now I am getting this error

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60e6dac530ee161c70b70f77, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)>]>`

Comment: If you are using atlas to host your mongo server, you might have to whitelist its IP, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60920692/6203472. Please consider accepting the answer, the second error is a different problem :)